# Why am I getting Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Trying to run Dockerfile and it fails at installing npm.

ERROR:

```
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y npm' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

MAINTAINER Giacomo Vacca "giacomo.vacca@gmail.com"

ENV REFRESHED_AT 2015-01-19
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get autoremove
RUN npm -v

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl --silent --location http://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential

RUN rm /usr/bin/node

# needs this to find the nodejs exec
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

RUN apt-get install -y npm  <--- FAIL
RUN /usr/bin/npm install socket.io@0.9.14

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/node", "/root/server.js"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install npm from the ubuntu distribution with:

```
RUN apt-get install -y npm
```

because it's already installed by the nodejs package from nodesource. You can check it with:

```
dpkg -L nodejs | grep "/usr/bin/npm"
```

Comment: I took out that line and now getting /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

Comment: I had to move the RUN npm -v below the install of node. It worked moving that line.